# Can't set cookie with jquery click function in UI modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, jquery-cookie

This script sets the cookie perfectly fine when it's coded to set the cookie on page load, but because of earlier issues, I need to set the cookie when you click to 'X' out of the modal that pops up on initial page load. I have been messing around for 2 hours now and cannot for the life of me get this thing to work. Any selector I have called within the jQuery UI modal with jQuery will not work. I have even tried $('a') and I can set the cookie by clicking any other link on the page after I close the modal, but the modal itself will not do the trick. I separated the code into two small scripts as a last ditch effort.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function(){
  var check_cookie = $.cookie('ss_manifesto');
   if(check_cookie == null){
  $("#ModalMessage").dialog({modal: true});
   }
});
</script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.modal_close').click(function(){
     $.cookie('ss_manifesto', '1', { expires: 7 });
    alert('test');
  });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: a) Are you sure your second shown script runs after first one, not before? b) Are you sure about `.modal_close`? For me it is `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close`.

Comment: I edited that so people who don't use jQuery ui would set it more clearly. It is .ui-dialog-titlebar-close

Comment: Look, [it works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/72n9G/). What about you?

Comment: I really don't know what was causing the issue. It was on a Shopify store with about 15+ other scripts loaded. But I ended up dropping the jQuery UI, and creating the modal with reveal.js, and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your efforts though.